# Printing the percentage of a color in an image in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, colors

I have this python script which takes in an image and outputs the percentage of green and brown color in that image. I need help to understand the below stated line because I want to implement this code in another language.

```
    img = cv2.imread('__FILE_LOCATION__')
    grid_HSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_green = np.array([25,52,72])
    upper_green = np.array([102,255,255])

    lower_brown = np.array([10, 100, 20])
    upper_brown = np.array([20, 255, 200])

    mask= cv2.inRange(grid_HSV, lower_green, upper_green)
    brown_mask= cv2.inRange(grid_HSV, lower_brown, upper_brown)

    print(str(round(((mask>0).mean())*100,3)))                 #<- This line
    print(str(round(((brown_mask>0).mean())*100,3)))           #<- and This line

    # what is "mask>0" part, ".mean()" part and why multiply with 100
```

Below is the Java implementation of my above python code. It is just missing the percentage calculation part. I need help in completing this.

```
    oImage = imread(pathOfFile);
    hsvImage = new Mat();
    color_range1 = new Mat();
    color_range2 = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(oImage, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    Core.inRange(hsvImage, new Scalar(25,52,72), new Scalar(102,255,255), color_range1); // Green
    Core.inRange(hsvImage, new Scalar(10, 100, 20), new Scalar(20, 255, 200), color_range2); // Brown



    // Finding percentage of green and brown colors from above masks.



    color_range1.release();
    color_range2.release();
    hsvImage.release();
    oImage.release();
```

Comment: Read up on [object.__gt__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__)

Comment: `mask` is a numpy array. `mask>0` returns a numpy array of booleans, signifying for each element whether it satisfies that condition. Apparently calling `mean` on array of booleans treats each `False` as `0` and each `True` as `1`, and calculates a mean of that. Multiplied by 100 you get percentage. i.e. percentage of values where `mask` is non-zero (it's unsigned). And since `mask` is a result of `inRange` call, which sets matching values to 255, it's a percentage of green pixels in the image.

Comment: @Dan Mašek I need to implement this python code in java. I have completed the java code till the inRange calls for the two masks. Can you help me complete it to calculate the percentage of both green and brown colors.

Comment: @Dan Mašek hey can you help me???

Comment: There's a function [`Core.countNonZero`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Core.html#countNonZero(org.opencv.core.Mat)) (should be obvious what it does from the name), and [`Mat.total()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#total()) gives total number of pixels.

Comment: @Dan Mašek can you share the whole part.

Comment: @Dan Mašek how can i implement that in my java code.

Answer (score 0):

Get your mask, then divide the number of pixels with a color match (non zeros) by the total number of pixels (size of mask array) times 100. Rounding to the first decimal place would be nice too:

```
round(np.count_nonzero(mask) / np.size(mask) * 100, 1)
```